# Swift : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: xcode, swift

Hi I am brand new to swift and need some help

Every time I run my code my app crashes and spits out a " the above error

Can anyone please tell me what I need to do or what I need to replace in my code?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    var employeeNames = ["John","Jane","Jack","James"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return employeeNames.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return employeeNames [row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print(employeeNames[row])
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely fine, so the only alternative is that you haven't hooked up your pickerView outlet. Ctrl click on your picker view in the storyboard and see if your outlet 'picker' shows up. If it doesn't then ctrl drag from the pickerView to your outlet to hook it up.

Comment: I've done this and the pickerView appears to already be hooked up, do you know of any other reason I could be getting this error? Is there a way to drill down and find the error specifically, my problem then will be trying to understand the error

Comment: This error usually means that there was a variable or implicitly unwrapped optional that is nil when trying to access it. That's why I figured that the picker outlet want connected because that's the only thing that could be found to be nil.

Comment: Was there more than one outlet connected to the pickerView? that sometimes does it. Also maybe rename your view controller as PickerViewController or something and then set your storyboard ViewController as that class (I don't think that is the problem but worth a shot)